# Django on CPanel, can't install requirements.txt

Tags: django, pip, cpanel, requirements.txt, godaddy-api

I am trying to publish a Django web-application using CPanel. I created the python application but when I tried to install requirements.txt (using python version 3.8.18), I get

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified 
error: subprocess-exited-with-error    
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.  
│ exit code: 1  ╰─> See above for output.    
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

This is my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.1
attrs==20.3.0
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
cryptography==37.0.2
defusedxml==0.7.1
device-detector==5.0.1
distlib==0.3.4
Django==4.0.4
django-allauth==0.52.0
django-cors-headers==3.13.0
django-filter==22.1
django-user-agents==0.4.0
djangorestframework==3.13.1
filelock==3.7.1
geonamescache==1.5.0
google-auth==2.16.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.8.0
httplib2==0.21.0
idna==3.3
jellyfish==0.9.0
joblib==1.2.0
lib50==3.0.4
Markdown==3.3.7
markdown2==2.4.3
networkx==3.0
numpy==1.24.2
oauthlib==3.2.2
pbr==5.9.0
pexpect==4.8.0
Pillow==9.1.0
pipenv==2022.7.4
platformdirs==2.5.2
pomegranate==0.14.8
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
pygame==2.2.0
PyJWT==2.6.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2022.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
regex==2022.10.31
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
scipy==1.10.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
stevedore==4.0.0
submit50==3.1.1
termcolor==1.1.0
ua-parser==0.16.1
urllib3==1.26.9
user-agents==2.2.0
virtualenv==20.15.1
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
whitenoise==6.4.0
```

I have previously published web apps using Django and CPanel. For some reason, it will not install this time. How can I make the packages install properly?